# base_scan has no intensity

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Why does 'base_scan' laser scan in PR2 have an empty array of intensities?
rostopic echo /base_scan
...
intensities: []

Thanks,

Rony

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65129/base_scan-has-no-intensity/) by [Rony](https://answers.ros.org/users/5148/rony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The laser is either configured not to send intensities, or is not capable of doing so.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0